# I badly need to generate the following table

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I need to generate the following table. I wrote this code and got the output in fig 1.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}

    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline

        \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Performance measure}\\ \hline
        evaluation metric&Proposed method&traditional method\\ \hline
        DC&0.0019&0.0021 \\ \hline
        JS&0.9975&0.9916\\ \hline
        DSC&0.9987&0.9958\\ \hline


    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

fig 1. [image]

but I need to generate the table in fig 2.

[image]

Please help me to generate the table in fig 2 in latex

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE: Well, using `\cline{2-4}` could help for the lines from column 2 to 4

Comment: ... and multirow. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167367/124842

Answer (score 8):

Here's a slightly different solution, this one using `booktabs`. I know this does away with some of OP's formatting, but I also know many of us subscribe to the notion that vertical rules ruin tables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{*{5}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Performance measure} & \\ \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    Paper title & Evaluation metric & Proposed method & Traditional method & Image type \\ \midrule
    & DC & 0.0019 & 0.0021 \\
    & JS & 0.9975 & 0.9916 \\
    & DSC & 0.9987 & 0.9958 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Although if OP goes this route, s/he may wish to redesign some elements of the table for clarity of data.)

Comment: Does your proposed method allow for automatic line-breaking inside cells?

Comment: No, but I'm also a `\footnotesize` tablemaker. @Zarko's answer addresses this, however.

Answer (score 6):

*Edit:*
In the first attempt I miss one column, so I decide to delete this version of answer ... the second version is:

[image]

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{booktabs, tabularx}
    \newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{5}{C}}
            \toprule    
        &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Performance measure}                         &               \\ 
            \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
    Paper\newline title 
        &   evaluation metric   &   Proposed method &   traditional method  &   image\newline type  \\
        \midrule
        &   DC                  &   0.0019          &   0.0021              &               \\
        &   JS                  &   0.9975          &   0.9916              &               \\
        &   DSC                 &   0.9987          &   0.9958              &               \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
From question is not clear if the paper title is for all tree rows or for each row separately. In both case it can be expected that paper title is longer than cell width, consequently it would be broken into more lines. In the first case the lines can take vertical space of three rows (using `multirow` cell), se MWE below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\setlength\hsize{1.8\hsize}}C 
                        *{4}{>{\setlength\hsize{0.8\hsize}}C} C}
        \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Performance measure}                         &                           \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-4}
Paper\newline title
    &   evaluation metric   &   Proposed method &   traditional method  &   image\newline type      \\
    \midrule
\multirow{3}{=}{Comparison of image evaluation methods}
    &   DC                  &   0.0019          &   0.0021              &   \multirow{3}{=}{Lena}   \\
    &   JS                  &   0.9975          &   0.9916              &                           \\
    &   DSC                 &   0.9987          &   0.9958              &                           \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you plz tell me how to add a paper name in the cell under " Paper title" and under under "Image type" cell? I tried but failed

Comment: @HafsaMoontariAli, see addendum to my answer. I added "paper title" and "image name". Also I changed table design by introducing `multirow` package. and changes column width.

Answer (score 6):

Or this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\setcellgapes{4pt}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

    \begin{center}
\sffamily\makegapedcells
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
\multirow{3}{*}[-4.4pt]{Paper title} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Performance measure} & \multirow{3}{*}[-4.4pt]{Image type}\\
\cline{2-4}
       & \makecell{Evaluation\\ metric}& \makecell{Proposed\\ method} & \makecell{Traditional\\ method} & \\ \hline
         & DC&0.0019&0.0021 & \\ \hline
         & JS&0.9975&0.9916 & \\ \hline
        & DSC&0.9987&0.9958 & \\ \hline


    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the outer columns and use `\multirow` for the upper outer cells. I also used `tabularx` instead since it looks like you want equal sized columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
      \hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{Paper title} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Performance measure} & 
      \multirow{2}{*}{Image type}\\ \cline{2-4}
      & evaluation metric & Proposed method & traditional method &\\ \hline
      & DC  & 0.0019 & 0.0021 & \\ \cline{2-4}
      & JS  & 0.9975 & 0.9916 & \\ \cline{2-4}
      & DSC & 0.9987 & 0.9958 & \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Second version**

Actually it is not needed to have a `\multirow` in the table head, it is easier to just leave the upper row of the first and last colmns empty and type in the second. To get a paper title spanning more than one row one would need `\multirow`. I have also used it in the last column.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|p{0.25\linewidth}|X|X|X|p{0.2\linewidth}|}
      \hline
      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Performance measure} & \\ \cline{2-4}
      \strut\newline Paper title
      & evaluation metric & Proposed method & traditional method & 
      \strut\newline Image type\\ \hline
      \multirow{3}{\linewidth}{A Comparison of new methods for images}
      & DC  & 0.0019 & 0.0021 & 
      \multirow{3}{\linewidth}{Baboon}\\ \cline{2-4}
      & JS  & 0.9975 & 0.9916 & \\ \cline{2-4}
      & DSC & 0.9987 & 0.9958 & \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The two `\strut\newline`s are used to move `Paper Title` and `Image Type` down to the second line. If you want them aligned with the top rows of the Method cells, just remove it.

Comment: Would you plz tell me how to add a paper name in the cell under " Paper title" and under under "Image type" cell? I tried but failed.

Comment: @HafsaMoontariAli; There is a second version adding paper name and image type texts.