# LaTeX code for table with multiple rows and columns

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

Can someone help with code this table in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. There are many examples of multirow and multicolumn table on this site, see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167367/101651 for example. Please try to do something by yourself and then add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your post. As is, your question is a _just-do-it-for-me_ one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of solutions, with or without vertical rules:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
Table~\ref{yours} is as your image.
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Categorical classification of variables\label{yours}}
    \begin{tabular}{|LL|LL|C|C|}
        \cline{5-6}
        \multicolumn{4}{c|}{}& \multicolumn{2}{C|}{Y_{i}}\\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{}&\text{Yes $(1)$}& \text{No $(0)$} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& 1 & a & b \\
        \cline{4-6}
        \multirow{2}{*}{$X_{i}$} & 0 & X_{i_{1}} & 2 & c & d \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & 1 & X_{i_{2}} & 1 & e & f \\
        \cline{4-6} 
        &&& 2 & g & h \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Table~\ref{mine} is without vertical rules.
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Categorical classification of variables\label{mine}}
    \begin{tabular}{LLLLCC}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{}& \multicolumn{2}{C}{Y_{i}}\\
        \cline{5-6}
        \multicolumn{4}{c}{}&\text{Yes $(1)$}& \text{No $(0)$} \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{2}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}& 1 & a & b \\
        \cline{4-6}
        \multirow{2}{*}{$X_{i}$} & 0 & X_{i_{1}} & 2 & c & d \\
        \cline{2-6}
        & 1 & X_{i_{2}} & 1 & e & f \\
        \cline{4-6} 
        &&& 2 & g & h \\ 
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the cell content is plain text instead of in math mode, just change `L` and `C` (the new column types I created) into `l` and `c`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use the package multirow (http://ftp.fau.de/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/multirow/multirow.pdf) and if needed tabularx. It provides the possibilities to combine cells in a row or column.

Edit: A code example (sry for forgetting that). It's not the hole table but it should give a feeling what to do with multicolumn and multirow.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ll|ll|}
    \cline{3-4}
  & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$Y$}\\
  \multirow{3}{*}{X} & & &a\\\cline{4-4}
  & & &b \\ \cline{4-4}
  & & &c \\ \cline{4-4}
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. And even though the the question does not have a lot of code in it, your answer could definitely benefit from expansion and a code example. At the moment it feels more like a comment.