# Latex code for table: how to merge rows and colum

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I am stuck on writing the latex code of this table. I have tried the following code:

```
\begin{array}{ | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | }
\hline
    \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
    \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
    \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
    USA sample &  &  & Italian sample &  &  & \  \\ \hline
    Sign & Capabilities & Magnitude & Sign & Capabilities & Magnitude & \  \\ \hline
    Positive & Active Listening & 7.34 & Positive & Fluency of Ideas & 7.93 & \  \\ \hline
     & Speech Recognition & 6.97 &  & Operation Analysis & 2.46 & \  \\ \hline
     & Deductive Reasoning & 5.72 &  & Problem Sensitivity & 2.95 & \  \\ \hline
     & Coordination & 4.41 &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
     & System Evaluation & 3.45 &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
    Negative & Social Perceptiveness & -9.39 & Negative & Social Perceptiveness & -3.681 &  \\ \hline
     & Originality & -6.14 &  & Originality & -3.47 &  \\ \hline
     & Speech Clarity & -5.65 &  & Complex Problem Solving & -2.76 &  \\ \hline
     & Oral Comprehension & -3.87 &  & Spatial Orientation & -2.5499999999999998 & \  \\ \hline
     & Visualization & -3.62 &  & Finger Dexterity & -2.0979999999999999 & \  \\ \hline
     & Spatial Orientation & -1.17 &  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
    Non-significant & Problem Sensitivity & -2.12 & Non-significant & Oral Comprehension & -2.3090000000000002 & \  \\ \hline
     & Fluency of Ideas & -1.9 &  & Deductive Reasoning & -2.09 & \  \\ \hline
     & Oral Expression & -1.04 &  & Manual Dexterity & -2.08 & \  \\ \hline
     & Manual Dexterity & -0.155 &  & Visualization & -1.22 & \  \\ \hline
     & Finger Dexterity & 0.95499999999999996 &  & Coordination & -0.4 & \  \\ \hline
     & Operation Analysis & 0.27 &  & Speech Clarity & 0.23 & \  \\ \hline
     & Complex Problem Solving & 1.84 &  & Oral Expression & 0.245 & \  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  & Speech Recognition & 1.37 & \  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  & System Evaluation & 1.4 & \  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  & Active Listening & 2.3199999999999998 & \  \\ \hline
\end{array}
```

But it is not correct because it doesn't merge the row(s) as I would like.
Can someone provide hints or suggestions?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since [it automatically appears in the lower right corner](//tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures) of your post.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You could use `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` (see e.g. [Combining multirow and multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167366/123129))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just one version (my view) how to make it a table that even fits into a document:

[image: table]

I've done the following:

- use `tabular` instead of `array` (it is not math)
- use `booktabs` package, remove all vertical rules and most horizontal rules
- remove all unnecessary duplication (incl. extra columns and rows)
- use a more uniform layout by reducing the amount of decimal places to 2 (the `S` column type can be set up to perform automatic rounding)
- align numbers on decimal markers

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your caption here}
\sisetup{table-format=-1.2, round-mode=places}
\begin{tabular}{ l lS lS }
    \toprule
    Sign & \multicolumn{2}{c}{USA sample} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Italian sample}\\ 
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}
     & Capabilities & {Magnitude} & Capabilities & {Magnitude}\\ \midrule
    Positive & Active Listening & 7.34 & Fluency of Ideas & 7.93 \\ 
     & Speech Recognition & 6.97 &  Operation Analysis & 2.46\\ 
     & Deductive Reasoning & 5.72 & Problem Sensitivity & 2.95\\ 
     & Coordination & 4.41 &  &  \\ 
     & System Evaluation & 3.45 &  & \\\addlinespace
    Negative & Social Perceptiveness & -9.39 & Social Perceptiveness & -3.681\\ 
     & Originality & -6.14 &  Originality & -3.47 \\ 
     & Speech Clarity & -5.65  & Complex Problem Solving & -2.76 \\ 
     & Oral Comprehension & -3.87 &  Spatial Orientation & -2.5499999999999998 \\ 
     & Visualization & -3.62 &  Finger Dexterity & -2.0979999999999999 \\ 
     & Spatial Orientation & -1.17 &  & \\ \addlinespace
    Non-significant & Problem Sensitivity & -2.12 & Oral Comprehension & -2.3090000000000002 \\ 
     & Fluency of Ideas & -1.9 &  Deductive Reasoning & -2.09 \\ 
     & Oral Expression & -1.04 &  Manual Dexterity & -2.08 \\ 
     & Manual Dexterity & -0.155 & Visualization & -1.22 \\ 
     & Finger Dexterity & 0.95499999999999996 &  Coordination & -0.4 \\ 
     & Operation Analysis & 0.27 &  Speech Clarity & 0.23 \\ 
     & Complex Problem Solving & 1.84  & Oral Expression & 0.245 \\ 
     &  &   & Speech Recognition & 1.37 \\ 
     &  &   & System Evaluation & 1.4 \\ 
     &  &   & Active Listening & 2.3199999999999998 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @RobertaBenetti If this answered your question, feel free to accept this answer by ticking the checkmark symbol on the left.

Comment: Hey sorry to bother you again! I have a correlation matrix made by 18 element and I need to rotate it in vertical. Do you have any suggestion? I attach the code I used below. Many many thanks.

Comment: @RobertaBenetti Please just ask a new question here. This forum works by using the question-answer mechanism.