# \multirow and \multicolumn

Tags: tables

hey guys I need to put this sentence on two different rows but I'm not able to use `\multirow` together with `\multicolumn`. Can you help me?

```
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} r S S @{}}
\midrule\multicolumn{3}{c} {The displayed standard errors are robust and clustered at country level. Level of statistical significance of coefficients:)}
\midrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you post a compilable code? Why do you want to use `multirow` since you have a single row?

Comment: because the row exits the sheet

Comment: Yes, but we need to know what the real situation looks like.

Comment: \begin{document}\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} r S S @{}}
    \toprule\midrule\multicolumn{3}{c}{\multirow{20}{l} {The displayed standard errors are robust and clustered at country level. Level of statistical significance of coefficients:$\*\*\*$(1$\%$), $\*\*$(5$\%$), $\*$(10$\%$).}}
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center} \end{document}

Comment: That's not compilable :-(

Comment: now? I cannot copy the whole text it says too long

Comment: That is not what Bernard means. He asks you to post something that can be copied and tested as is without having to guess stuff. You offer no preamble here. Btw I'd just use a `\parbox` inside the multicolumn, no need for multirow. Ask g for a full minimal example is standard here. Makes it a lot easier for others to test code and help

Comment: This should work I tested it:


\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} r S S @{}}
    \toprule
                & {$Y_{i_t}$}           & {$I_{i_t}$}       \\
\midrule\multicolumn{3}{c}{The displayed standard errors are robust and clustered at country level. Level of statistical significance of coefficients:$\*\*\*$(1$\%$), $\*\*$(5$\%$), $\*$(10$\%$).}
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end document}

Comment: Perhaps this post will help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167367/121944

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you're looking for is to use a `p` type column as in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/166746/121944).

Thus, substitute something like `\multicolumn{3}{p{4cm}}` where you currently have `\multicolumn{3}{c}`.

Comment: @federica Please accept the answer so that everyone knows the issue doesn't need any more attention.