# Problem with setting up vertical lines in booktabs tables

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn, booktabs

As pointed out [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167366/combining-multirow-and-multicolumn) it is important to use

> \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{}

in the following line of `multicolumn`.

Nevertheless I am struggling around with the same issue (unconnected vertical lines) and can't find a solution for it:

[image]

Here is how far I got. Any ideas would be great.

```
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll|cc@{}} \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} \\
\cmidrule(r){3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & A & B\\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{\thead{Text1 and \\ Text2}}} & C & \thead{1\\and 1}& 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & D & 3 & \thead{4\\ and 4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}} \quad
```

Comment: The line between Text1andText2 and C / D maybe should stay as it is.

Comment: The issue is not the same as the linked question. The gaps you see is because you are using vertical rules with `booktabs`. The `booktabs` documentation emphasizes "Never, ever use vertical rules". If you replace the `\toprule`, `\bottomrule` and `\midrule` by `\hline` the gaps will close. Better to remove the vertical rules, though.

Comment: please look at the documentation for booktabs, the package author makes it clear he thinks vertical rules are evil and by design the package makes them unusable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Booktabs` sets a vertical padding above and below its rules. You can set this padding to 0, and enjoy the other functionalities. Anyway, with `\arraystretch` set to `2`, do you really need it? If necessary, you can replace it with the `\setcellgapes` command from `makecell`. I took the opportunity to slightly simplify the code of your table, with the `\multirowthead` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\centering
\aboverulesep = 0pt
\belowrulesep = 0pt
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll|cc@{}} \toprule
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} \\
\cmidrule(r){3-4}
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & A & B\\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\multirowthead{2}[-1ex]{Text1 and \\ Text2}} & C & \thead{1\\and 1}& 2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & D & 3 & \thead{4\\ and 4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} \quad

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the support and simplification as well!

Comment: Interesting to see that there is no "multicolumnthead"

Comment: @KLJ: Yes, that's a mystery to me.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the `booktabs` documentation (and with that in the comments above) I tried it without the vertical lines and have to admit that it looks better now:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}    

{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}%
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Text} \\
\cmidrule(r){2-3}
\thead{Text1 and \\ Text2} & A & B\\
\midrule
C & \thead{1\\and 1}& 2 \\
D & 3 & \thead{4\\ and 4} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}} \quad

\end{document}
```

Comment: often it also (if space permits) looks better if you space it out, aka add more horizontal space

Comment: That is true. I my case it doesn't. But if other (also) wonder how to add horizontal spcae: {\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2em} TABLE }

Comment: That is not a good way, this evenly added space everywhere, not really what we want. Often we want space between columns. I have a tendency to introduce extra columns just for this.