# How to split table cell into multiple columns?

Tags: tables, latex3, split

I am trying to achieve below table show in the figure, but I couldn't succeed it. I tried the below code.

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
Dataset & Model & Evaluation criteria & Rank &  &  &  \\
 &  & RMSE & MAPE & MAE & R &  \\
(A) & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & FN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & NN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & RX &  &  &  &  &  \\
(B) & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & FN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & NN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & RX &  &  &  &  &  \\
(C) & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & FN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & NN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & ARX &  &  &  &  &  \\
(D) & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & FFN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & LNN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 & ARX &  &  &  &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Combining multirow and multicolumn](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167366/combining-multirow-and-multicolumn)

Comment: @ingli-- you need to add an example with rotated text like in the first column

Comment: Are you sure you want to rotate the entries in the first column? I see no reason to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to  load `multirow`and `rotating` for that . The `makecell` package will also be useful, as it allows for line breaks and common formatting in standard cells. Furthermore, you can define some vertical padding to cells  with the `\setcellgapes` command.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{array, rotating}
\usepackage{multirow, makecell}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={8in, 10in}]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering\sffamily
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\setcellgapes{1ex}\makegapedcells
\begin{tabular}{*{6}{c|}c}
\hline
\multirowthead{2}{Dataset} & \multirowthead{2}{Model} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\bfseries Evaluation criteria} & \multirowthead{2}{Rank} \\
\cline{3-6}
 & & \textbf{RMSE} & \textbf{MAPE} & \textbf{MAE} & \textbf{R} & \\
 \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\turnbox{90}{(A)}} & Proposed & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & FN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & NN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & RX & & & & & \\
 \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\turnbox{90}{(B)}} & Proposed & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & FN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & NN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & RX & & & & & \\
 \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\turnbox{90}{(C)}} & Proposed & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & FN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & NN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & ARX & & & & & \\
 \hline
\multirow{6}{*}{\turnbox{90}{(D)}} & Proposed & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & FFN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & LNN & & & & & \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & ARX & & & & & \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{Dataset} & \multirow{2}{*}{Model} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Evaluation criteria}   &  \multirow{2}{*}{Rank} \\ 
\cline{3-6}
 &  & RMSE & MAPE & MAE & R &  \\
 \hline
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{(A)}} & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{2-7}
 & FN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & NN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & RX &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{1-7}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{(B)}} & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{2-7}
 & FN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & NN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & RX &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{1-7}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{(C)}} & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{2-7}
 & FN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & NN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & ARX &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{1-7}
\multirow{4}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{(D)}} & Proposed &  &  &  &  &  \\
\cline{2-7}
 & FFN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & LNN &  &  &  &  &  \\
 \cline{2-7}
 & ARX &  &  &  &  &\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{(X)}` would be better.